# Manipulate - Flickering graphics

Tags: manipulate

I am new to mathematica and was experimenting with NDSolve and doing a simple demonstration of orbital motion and Newtons laws. I put together the following code which all seems to work except the Graphics object at the origin seems to flicker/move ? I tried moving the graphics object that displays this object to the initialisation section but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried trackedsymbols but that doesn't work either. Any ideas/suggestions much appreciated.

```
Module[{t,tfinal=20,x0=1.5,y0=1.0,xv0=0.2,yv0=0.5,range = {{-3,3},{-3,3}},eqs,sol,fx,fy},
eqs = {y''[t]+y[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)^(3/2)==0,x''[t]+x[t]/(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)^(3/2)==0,x'[0]==xv0,y'[0]==yv0,x[0]==x0,y[0]==y0};
sol = Flatten @ NDSolve[eqs,{x,y},{t,tfinal}];
fx[t_]:=x[t] /. sol;
fy[t_]:= y[t] /. sol;
Manipulate[
g =Graphics[{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point@ {fx[t],fy[t]}},PlotRange->range];
Show[p,g,p1],
{t,0,tfinal},
Initialization :> {p=ParametricPlot[{{fx[k],fy[k]}},{k,0,tfinal},PlotRange->range,PlotLabel->"Planetary motion"],p1=Graphics[{Blue,PointSize[0.03],Point[{0,0}]},PlotRange->range]}
]
]
```

[image]

Here's an `ImageDifference` of two adjacent frames of a screen recording of the animation:

[image: image difference of two frames]

The central dot has moved sideways...

Comment: In your example, `time` is undefined. Nevertheless, when I set it to any numerical value, the example works as expected. If you refer to the fact that the red dot moves so fast around `{0,0}` that it seems to cut through some distance, you could try holding down the **Alt** key while moving the slider which slows down updating. For me it shows a smooth movement around the focus.

Comment: Same as @IstvánZachar here Mma v 8.0

Comment: And don't include `t` into the module vars, as it's localized by Manipulate[]

Comment: @belisarius I was wondering about that myself. Does it really matter? No value of `t` gets out of the `Manipulate` to the `Module`, thus updating `t` does not cause interference with the symbolic nature of `t` in the equations. Generally of course I agree with you, but does it really have any risk here (apart from giving `t` any value in the `Module`)?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I think it's simply not necessary  to scope it

Comment: Yes, for me the blue dot does appear to move very slightly around the origin as you move the slider. The effect is very slight, though.

Comment: @cormullion, David: What OS do you use? I cannot see the blue point moving a nanopixel no matter how hard I look.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'm on  Mac OS Mountain Lion, Mathematica 9. The sideways oscillation of the blue dot is apparent. I'll add a frame to the question if I can.

Comment: The flickering disappears (for me) with `Show[p, g, p1, ImageSize -> 500]`... ‽